# SOAP alone is for compatability and with WSRF for stateful communications?

Tags: web-services, soap, compatibility, conceptual, stateful

I know this might be a very basic question but I read so many articles on SOAP and I need to make sure I got it right.

In brief, I use **SOAP** because it's build on **XML** and thus I can have a standarized way to enable **compatible** communications between incompatible systems (in terms of OSs, architectures, programming languages, APIs, ...).

But still SOAP is statelss. And so to make it **stateful**, SOAP needs to be used along with **WSRF** (Web Service Resource Framework).

Qustion: *Is my basic understanding right? Kindly correct me or illustrate more.*